# Configuring mock-cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking, mocha.js

I'm trying to use [mock-cli](https://github.com/timkendrick/mock-cli) to stub process.arv in mocha tests for a cli app. I want to test that a message is console.logged when an incorrect argument ("imit") is passed to process.argv (as defined by commands).

I'm trying to adapt the example from the documentation but i don't think i have set everything up correctly.

1. it passes when i comment out "`stdin: require('../mocks/fakeInputStream'), // Hook up a fake input stream`" though i know it's not working correctly
2. it fails with `TypeError: sourceStream.on is not a function` when run as described below

Can someone see what I'm missing?

/index.js

```
  var commands = ['init'];

  function getGitHeadArgs() {
      return process.argv.slice(2, process.argv.length);
    }

if (getGitHeadArgs().length) {
  if (!commands.includes(getGitHeadArgs()[0])) {
    console.log("Silly Githead! That's not a githead command");
  }
  eval(getGitHeadArgs()[0])();
} else {
  console.log("You didn't tell githead to do anything!");
}
```

/testIndex.js

```
var assert = require('assert');
var index = require('../index.js');
var mockCli = require("mock-cli");

describe("incorrect argument", function() {

      it("imit throws an error if an invalid command is raised", function() {

        var argv = ['node', '../index.js', 'imit']; // Fake argv

        var stdio = {
          stdin: require('../mocks/fakeInputStream'), // Hook up a fake input stream
          stdout: process.stdout, // Display the captured output in the main console
          stderr: process.stderr // Display the captured error output in the main console
        };

        var kill = mockCli(argv, stdio, function onProcessComplete(error, result) {
          var exitCode = result.code; // Process exit code
          var stdout = result.stdout; // UTF-8 string contents of process.stdout
          var stderr = result.stderr; // UTF-8 string contents of process.stderr

          assert.equal(exitCode, 0);
          assert.equal(stdout, "Silly Githead! That's not a githead command\n");
          assert.equal(stderr, '');
        });

        // Execute the CLI task
        require('../index.js');

        // Kill the task if still running after one second
        setTimeout(kill, 1000);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

- Is `../mocks/fakeInputStream` a valid path?
- Is the object at `../mocks/fakeInputStream` a valid instance of `ReadableStream`?

> The [source code](https://github.com/timkendrick/mock-cli/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sourceStream) is avalible at GitHub.

Make sure you meet the requirements for the  `captureStdin(sourceStream, callback)` function.
The module uses that function to capture your `fakeInputStream` and pipe it into a `captureStream`.